# How to I hide a link?

Tags: html, hidden

I was wondering how to hide a content, especially a link (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9IVD.jpg), in a website template and blogger template 
Just if a script code is used or an html tag or something like that, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it is html link, You can make the link invisible or display none by using css.

```
a { display:none }
```

or

```
a {visibility:hidden}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using some template which is showing its link back. Proper option is to buy that template.

Although if you want to hide specific element you can use selectors.

```
For Id = #id
for class= .class
for name = [name=name]
```

and so on, search over internet if you want any other selector.

and the use css or jquery.

**CSS**

```
  #id {display: none}
```

**Jquery**

```
 $("#Id").hide();
```